# Can a double initialized with a small whole number value be used with accuracy in a BigDecimal context?

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

It is well documented that using a double can lead to inaccuracies and that BigDecimal guarantees accuracy so long as there are no doubles in the mix.

However, is accuracy guaranteed if the double in question is a small whole number?

For example, although the following will be inaccurate/unsafe:

```
BigDecimal bdDouble = new BigDecimal(0.1d); // 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

will the following always be accurate/safe?

```
BigDecimal bdDouble = new BigDecimal(1.0d); // 1
```

Is it safe to assume that small whole number doubles are safe to use with BigDecimals - if so, what is the smallest whole number that would introduce an inaccuracy?

**>> Additional info in response to initial answers:**

Thanks for the answers. Very helpful.

Just to add a little more detail, I have a legacy interface which supplies doubles, but I can be certain that these doubles will represent whole numbers having being themselves converted from Strings to doubles via Double.parseDouble(String) where the String is a guaranteed whole number representation.

I do not want to create a new interface which passes me Strings or BigDecimals if I can avoid it.

I can immediately convert the double to a BigDecimal on my side of the interface and make all internal calculations using BigDecimal calls, but I want to be sure that is as safe as creating a new BigDecimal/String interface.

Given that in my original example using 0.1d does not accurately result in 0.1, as shown by the fact that the actual BigDecimal is 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625, it appears that some fractions will introduce an inaccuracy.

On the other hand, given that in my original example using 1.0d does accurately results in 1, it appears that whole numbers retain accuarcy. It appears that this is guaranteed up to a value of 2^53, if I understand your answers correctly.

Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: “It is well documented that […] BigDecimal guarantees accuracy so long as there are no doubles in the mix.” Have you ever tried to represent 1/3 using `BigDecimal`?

Comment: Btw you should use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` instead of `new BigDecimal(double)`.

Answer (score 7):

The `BigDecimal` aspect isn't as relevant to this question as "what is the range of integers that can be exactly represented in `double`?" - in that every finite `double` value can be represented exactly by `BigDecimal`, and that's the value you'll get if you call the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor. So you can be confident that if the value you wish to represent is an integer which is exactly representable by a `double`, if you pass that `double` to the `BigDecimal` constructor, you'll get a `BigDecimal` which exactly represents the same integer.

The significand of a `double` is 52 bits. Due to normalization, that means you should expect to be able to store integer values in the range [-2<sup>53</sup>, 2<sup>53</sup>] exactly. Those are pretty large numbers.

Of course, if you're only in the business of representing integers, it's questionable as to why you're using `double` at all... and you need to make sure that any conversions you're using from original source data to `double` aren't losing any information loss - but purely on the matter of "what range of integers are exactly representable as `double` values" I believe the above is correct...

Comment: The range is [-2^53, 2^53]. The first non-representable positive integer is 2^53+1.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Thanks. That was my *suspicion* due to normalization, but it's good to have confirmation.

Comment: The aspect of BigDecimal that is relevant is that any finite double number converts exactly to BigDecimal.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: True. I'll amenda the first paragraph.

Answer (score -2):

A short answer is no. Because of the way a floating point variable is stored in memory there is no "small" value 0.000001 uses the same number of bits as 100000, every value is represented in the same way 0.xxx..eyy

A better way to initialize a BigDecimal is to initialize it with a string.

> BigDecimal bdDouble = new BigDecimal("0.1");

Comment: The short answer to which question? If you mean "Is it safe to assume that small whole number doubles are safe to use with BigDecimals" the answer is *yes*, surely, as per my answer.

Comment: Every value, be it whole number or not, in floating point format is represented as 0.xxxxxxx...* 10^y the whole rounding up or down is up to the implementation of the floating point operations in the CPU, so using floating point variables may end up with different results on different PCs ... in a word no, it's not guaranteed

Comment: No, *not* 10^y, but 2^y (for `double`). And for normalized numbers, it's 1.xxxxx * 2^y. And while some aspects aren't guaranteed in terms of Java being able to use higher precision than specified in some cases unless you have `strictfp` turned on, the representation allows *all* integers in the range specified in my answer to be represented exactly. It's easy enough to tell you the exact representation of any of those values in IEEE-754 bit patterns...

Comment: Ah, unless by "10^y" you meant in binary, which would make sense, as the 1.xxxx would be in binary too, of course... That doesn't change the range of integers that can be exactly represented, of course...

Comment: @cosmin.danisor The question is tagged "java" so we can safely assume the Java `double` type as defined in the Java Language Specification. All integers in the range [-2^53, 2^53] are exactly representable in Java `double`, regardless of choice of CPU.